# What material should I use for a tent house like this?

Tags: materials

[image]

I'm planning to build a tent house like this in Paddy field. I'm totally new to this. I'm looking for the materials for tent. What is good recommendation for durable material for this?

Comment: That looks like a standard commercially-made pavillion tent, which would mean it's probably just canvas, maybe with a water-repellant treatment.  (Many summer camps in our area use tents much like this one, originally obtained as army surplus, but they can be purchased new.) The large cloth stretched over the entire platform is also probably a commercially-made drop cloth, most likely with a waterproof coating tjough ee can't bd sure from this view.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, that would be [duck canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_duck). You'd want treated canvas designed for tents that will help with water resistance and UV protection.

Comment: This is good tip that I can dig into. Tnx.